# How to display multiple items at per slide in bootstrap carousel with php

Tags: php, html, jquery, css

Hi guys I am trying to setup bottstrap carousel with multiple items (Display 4 items per slide).

I have read all questions and answers about this, but couldnt find a usefull answer.

I do it with 1 item at per slide as follow .

```
<div id="carousel-two" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner rounded-1">
     <?php 
      $i = 0;
      foreach($slider as $article){ 
       $show = '';
       $actives = '';
       if($i == 0){
         $actives = ' active';
       }
     ?>
    <div class="carousel-item <?php echo  $actives; ?>" data-bs-interval="5000">
       <a href="<?php echo $article['post_seo_url']; ?>-<?php echo $article['post_id']; ?>">
        <img src="http://localhost/ilan/assets/images/1by1/01.webp" class="d-block w-100 rounded-1" alt="..." width="100%" height="100%">
       </a>
      <div class="carousel-caption px-2">
        <a href="<?php echo $article['post_seo_url']; ?>-<?php echo $article['post_id']; ?>"><h1 class="text-white"><?php echo $article['post_title']; ?></h1></a>
      </div>
    </div>
   <?php  $i++; } ?>
  </div>
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
     <?php 
      $i = 0;
      foreach($slider as $slide){ 
       $actives = '';
       if($i == 0){
         $actives = ' class="active"';
       }
     ?>
      <li data-bs-target="#carousel-two" data-bs-slide-to="<?php echo  $i; ?>"<?php echo  $actives; ?>><?php echo  $i+1; ?></li>
     <?php  $i++; } ?>

  </ol>
</div>
```

But cant do it to display 4 items at per slide, I created an array and tried `array_slice();` and `array_chunk();` to split array in parts and display it. but had no luck.

**This is what I want to do** : Here is the html part of slider.

I dont want indicators in slider. that is why didn't include it in example.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="authors" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <div class="row gy-2">
        <div class="col-xl-12 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="row g-0">
              <div class="col-5">
                <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/trading-and-investment-concept-trader-silhouette-with-digital-tablet-picture-id1310316502?s=612x612" class="img-fluid rounded-1" alt="..." width="100%" height="100%">
              </div>
              <div class="col-7">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="card-text ps-1">This is a wider card with supporting text below.</h4>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-12 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="row g-0">
              <div class="col-5">
                <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/trading-and-investment-concept-trader-silhouette-with-digital-tablet-picture-id1310316502?s=612x612" class="img-fluid rounded-1" alt="..." width="100%" height="100%">
              </div>
              <div class="col-7">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="card-text ps-1">This is a wider card with supporting text below.</h4>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-12 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="row g-0">
              <div class="col-5">
                <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/trading-and-investment-concept-trader-silhouette-with-digital-tablet-picture-id1310316502?s=612x612" class="img-fluid rounded-1" alt="..." width="100%" height="100%">
              </div>
              <div class="col-7">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="card-text ps-1">This is a wider card with supporting text below.</h4>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-12 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="row g-0">
              <div class="col-5">
                <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/trading-and-investment-concept-trader-silhouette-with-digital-tablet-picture-id1310316502?s=612x612" class="img-fluid rounded-1" alt="..." width="100%" height="100%">
              </div>
              <div class="col-7">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="card-text ps-1">This is a wider card with supporting text below.</h4>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>  
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class="row gy-2">
        <div class="col-xl-12 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="row g-0">
              <div class="col-5">
                <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/trading-and-investment-concept-trader-silhouette-with-digital-tablet-picture-id1310316502?s=612x612" class="img-fluid rounded-1" alt="..." width="100%" height="100%">
              </div>
              <div class="col-7">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="card-text ps-1">This is a wider card with supporting text below.</h4>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-12 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="row g-0">
              <div class="col-5">
                <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/trading-and-investment-concept-trader-silhouette-with-digital-tablet-picture-id1310316502?s=612x612" class="img-fluid rounded-1" alt="..." width="100%" height="100%">
              </div>
              <div class="col-7">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="card-text ps-1">This is a wider card with supporting text below.</h4>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-12 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="row g-0">
              <div class="col-5">
                <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/trading-and-investment-concept-trader-silhouette-with-digital-tablet-picture-id1310316502?s=612x612" class="img-fluid rounded-1" alt="..." width="100%" height="100%">
              </div>
              <div class="col-7">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="card-text ps-1">This is a wider card with supporting text below.</h4>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-12 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="row g-0">
              <div class="col-5">
                <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/trading-and-investment-concept-trader-silhouette-with-digital-tablet-picture-id1310316502?s=612x612" class="img-fluid rounded-1" alt="..." width="100%" height="100%">
              </div>
              <div class="col-7">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="card-text ps-1">This is a wider card with supporting text below.</h4>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>  
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class="row gy-2">
        <div class="col-xl-12 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="row g-0">
              <div class="col-5">
                <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/trading-and-investment-concept-trader-silhouette-with-digital-tablet-picture-id1310316502?s=612x612" class="img-fluid rounded-1" alt="..." width="100%" height="100%">
              </div>
              <div class="col-7">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="card-text ps-1">This is a wider card with supporting text below.</h4>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-12 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="row g-0">
              <div class="col-5">
                <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/trading-and-investment-concept-trader-silhouette-with-digital-tablet-picture-id1310316502?s=612x612" class="img-fluid rounded-1" alt="..." width="100%" height="100%">
              </div>
              <div class="col-7">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="card-text ps-1">This is a wider card with supporting text below.</h4>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-12 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="row g-0">
              <div class="col-5">
                <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/trading-and-investment-concept-trader-silhouette-with-digital-tablet-picture-id1310316502?s=612x612" class="img-fluid rounded-1" alt="..." width="100%" height="100%">
              </div>
              <div class="col-7">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="card-text ps-1">This is a wider card with supporting text below.</h4>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-12 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="row g-0">
              <div class="col-5">
                <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/trading-and-investment-concept-trader-silhouette-with-digital-tablet-picture-id1310316502?s=612x612" class="img-fluid rounded-1" alt="..." width="100%" height="100%">
              </div>
              <div class="col-7">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="card-text ps-1">This is a wider card with supporting text below.</h4>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>  
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Any help would be greatfull. Thanks

Comment: perhaps use [array_chunk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) on $article, then simply looping over it, then for indicators use count($article), as it needs no data.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I tried that and it started displaying same items each time, probably my mistake. would you please give an example ?

Comment: see https://3v4l.org/EqcCQ

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thank you so much it works perfectly, would you please answer the question I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

bootstrap carousel assumes each slide as a carousel-item

so if you want one slide (.carousel-item) to have 4 items inside of it, you need to place each 4 articles of yours inside of same carousel-item

it's tricky and your items will slide 4 per each slide change

can't you try OwlCarousel inside of your project?
it's really nice and much better than BS Carousel...